# How to Find the Average Raster Value of an area defined by a shapefile using R?

Tags: r, spatial-statistics

I have a set of raster images which represent a specific month over the years, and I want to make a timeline of the average values of an area using a shapefile.

How do I extract the values from the rasters and import them in R in a manner that I can use them?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is example code. It is fairly straight forward to adapt this code to work in a loop for processing all of your rasters. If your rasters share a common extent and resolution you can create a raster stack and loop through the bands in the stack. To create a vector containing all rasters in a directory, in a specific format, you can use "list.files" and then pass this vector to stack.

Example:

```
rlist=list.files(getwd(), pattern="img$", full.names=TRUE) 

r <- stack(rlist)   


    # Add required libraries
    require(raster)
    require(sp)
    require(rgdal)

    # Set working directory, raster, in and out shapefiles
    setwd("C:/test")
    inshp="MyPolys"
    outshp="PolyMeans"
    rdata <- "Year2012.img"

    # Read polygon feature class shapefile
    sdata <- readOGR(dsn=getwd(), layer=inshp)

    # Read raster
    r <- raster(rdata)

    # Extract raster values to list object
    r.vals <- extract(r, sdata)

    # Use list apply to calculate mean for each polygon
    r.mean <- lapply(r.vals, FUN=mean)

    # Join mean values to polygon data
    sdata@data <- data.frame(sdata@data, m2012=r.mean)

    # Write results
    writeOGR(sdata, getwd(), outshp, driver="ESRI Shapefile", check_exists=TRUE, 
         overwrite_layer=TRUE)
```

Comment: +1 - excellent solution, well laid out and complete answer.

Comment: If I have a multipolygonfile: How does the `data.frame(sdata@data, m2012=r.mean)` know whch polygon to assign which value to?

Comment: to get r.mean added correctly to sdata I had to first unlist r.mean: r.mean <- unlist(lapply(r.vals, FUN=mean))

Answer (score 7):

Read the shapefile into a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` (`readOGR` function from package `rgdal`)

Read the raster into a `Raster` object (`raster` function from package `raster`)

Use `extract(raster, spdf)` to get the grid cells under each polygon. Then run `mean` on them.

Repeat over your set of raster images...

Comment: how to write the shapefile out (with the values extracted from the raster image)?

Answer (score 3):

Both answer above are great, I wanted to point out that the `raster::extract()` function does allow you to call functions within it.

```
r1 <- raster
p1 <- polygon feature

p1$mean_val <- raster::extract(x = r1, y = p1, FUN=mean)
```

Makes for a nice one liner for adding your summary values back to your polygon feature.